# Formatting output of a signed hex digits

Tags: c++, std, cout, stringstream

I have been using stringstream to convert my data and it has been working great except for one case.

I am subtracting two integer values that can end up being negative or positive. I take that value and send it to my `stringstream` object using `std::hex` as well as it gets dumped to `std::cout`.

My problem is my field for this value can only be 3 digits long and when I get a negative value it pads it with too many leading F's. I can't seem to get any std functions to help (`setw`, `setfill`, ...).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Example:

```
Value - Value = -9, So what I want is FF9 but what I get is FFFFFFF9.
```

My code to send the value to my stringstream object ss

```
ss << hex << value - LocationCounter;
```

Comment: What are the involved types actually? `unsigned int`, pointers?

Comment: Are you familiar with sign extension?

Comment: For one thing, `-9` is `FF..FF7`, not `FF..FF9`

Comment: The types are both ints.

Comment: @user366839 Whoops! You are right. I calculated too quick (or not at all).

Comment: @user366839 If you want a quick hack: convert the result to `signed short`. A short has fewer bits than an int, and the result will be less F's being printed :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks for the suggestion! I will do that until I can come up with a complete solution!

Comment: @Rakete1111: it is true that `signed short` would output fewer `F`s than an `int`, but the result of outputting `-9` as a `signed short` would still have 1 too many `F`s (`FFF7` instead of `FF7`).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to output a value that is 12 bits max in size.  There is no 12-bit data type, so the closest you can get is to use a 16-bit signed type with its high 4 bits set to 0.  For instance, calculate your desired value into an 8-bit signed type first (which will reduce its effective range to `-128 .. 127`), then sign-extend it to a 16-bit signed type, zero the high 4 bits, and finally output the result as hex:

```
signed char diff = (signed char)(value - LocationCounter);
// the setw() and setfill() are used to pad
// values that are 8 bits or fewer in size...
ss << hex << setw(3) << setfill('0') << (((signed short)diff) & 0x0fff);
```

To read the value back, read the 12-bit hex into a `signed short` and then truncate its value to a `signed char`:

```
signed short tmp;
ss >> hex >> tmp;
signed char diff = (signed char)tmp;
```